# Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions and SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I solve nonlinear optimization problem like this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) with SciPy:

Optimize: f(X) = x1^2 + x2^2

Constraint functions: x1 >= 0; x2 >= 0; x1 + 2*x2 <= 4

I wrote this:

```
import numpy as np

def func(X):
    x = X[0]
    y = X[1]
    L = X[2]
    return x**2 + y**2 + L * (x + 2*y - 4)

def dfunc(X):
    dLambda = np.zeros(len(X))
    h = 1e-3
    for i in range(len(X)):
        dX = np.zeros(len(X))
        dX[i] = h
        dLambda[i] = (func(X+dX)-func(X-dX))/(2*h);
    return dLambda

import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

X1 = fsolve(dfunc, [1, 1, 0])
print X1
```

I found only one solution: 0.8,1.6

But there are more: 0,0 4,0 0,2

How can I find it with SciPy?

Answer (score 5):

The fsolve solver is based on a search following the gradient of your function. You try to find a zero of a first derivative which you seem to approximate using finite differences? Please don't. The gradient of f is just (2*x1, 2*x2)

So the first derivative will be zero only at the origin.

The KKT conditions tell you that in a local extrema the gradient of f and the gradient of the constraints are aligned (maybe you want to read again about Lagrangian multipliers). So compute the gradient of your constraint function! But that's your homework...

Also note that all those algorithms tend to rely on a local search. So the starting point is rather crucial :-)

Good luck

Comment: Also keep in mind that in the corners of your triangle the concept of a gradient doesn't really make sense. Remember in the old days when looking for the minima/maxima of a differentiable function on a closed interval. Looking for f'(x) = 0 is good to find extrema in the interior of such an interval but you have to pay special attention to points at the boundary.